# Falstad Circuit - Why is the current still flowing through the transistors?

Tags: transistors, simulation, circuits, falstad

I'm trying to simulate a simple signal amplifying circuit using three transistors as shown below:

[image: Falstad Circuit, closed switch]

(Note that the LED isn't turned on)

But when I open the switch, the current still flows normally from the 9V source on the left, even though the first transistor's base doesn't receive tension. The current has the same value as before if you look at the bottom right corner. It should be zero.

Here's the image:

[image: Falstad circuit, open switch]

I'm very new to electronics and studying it on my own.

Comment: Just to clarify, the 9V source i mention is the one to the right of the LED and the 220Ohm resistor, just before the second switch.

Comment: why are you commenting on your own question? ... please edit the question and delete the comment ... this site is not a forum

Comment: Note that it's called voltage in English, not tension.

Comment: 10 V applied through the switch without a serial resistor is not really a good thing. And you need also to wire the negative "pole" of this voltage. However, transistors are characterized by a current Icbo (very very low) ... current through transistor with an "open base" ... which explains that you can measure a current ... at least through the diode.

Comment: Also note that because you don't have any ground reference, opening or closing the switch has absolutely zero impact on the circuit. There's nowhere for any current to flow from the +10 V input.

Comment: @Hearth If it doesn't bother you too much, could you please provide the corrected version of the circuit as answer? I don't know how i could insert the ground reference in it.

Comment: Presumably you want the negative side of that battery supply to be ground, right? That's where you should put your ground symbol. This is still not a correct circuit, though, because there's no current-limiting on the base of your transistors.

Comment: @Hearth yes, correct. Regarding the current that reaches the base of the transistors, i believe that the resistors were responsible to regulate it.

Comment: (With a proper input signal and a base resistor, 220 Ω still was a bit low (assuming 10 V for the battery) and 100 kΩ way high.)

Comment: `9V source on the left` (question body); [`Just to clarify, the 9V source i mention is the one …`](/q/694329/current-still-flowing#comment1848230_694329) - Do not put corrections/additions/clarifications in comments: edit the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out by others in comments ...
With the resistor at the input and wired ground of the 10 V, you should have a circuit like this.

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110)

[image]

NB: when the switch is open, values of currents and voltages are not very "meaningful".
The circuit is not really "complete".

Here is an example of some "resistors" added (switch open).

[image]